# localization of persistent menu on facebook bot

Tags: json, facebook, bots, botframework

I am using the below snippet to make my Facebook persistent menu localized...I used Node.js and made a request to the url mentioned in facebook documentation

It's giving me that the menu has been updated but still it's only showing in english only for all users even users that are using arabic language

```
{
    "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"ar_ar",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"postback",
          "title": "\u062a\u063a\u064a\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0629",
          "payload": "\u062a\u063a\u064a\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0629"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"en_us",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"postback",
          "title":"Change Language",
          "payload":"Change Language"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"postback",
          "title":"Change Language",
          "payload":"Change Language"
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: where do you add this? Channel data?

Comment: no , i send it as a request through node.js

Comment: Thank you, I used Postman :)